# Get back response from page and store into string

Tags: c#, web-services, api, facebook-graph-api

I want to submit a get to https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token and return the results into a string.

How do you do this in c#? I dont want the header and all that other stuff. Just the string that I could use for the api.

Comment: new WebClient().DownloadString(<url>) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to look at the [`WebClient`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.aspx) class.

It provides convenient method to download data from a given URI, for instance [`DownloadString(URI)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fhd1f0sw.aspx) .